# Totalling Payroll Hours by Employee

Tags: sql, ms-access

Okay, we have an Access database in which we record post production, non production and other hours each day for each employee. Employees may have days where their hours are split between projects.

For Payroll entry purposes, we have designed a report that totals the hours worked and calculates the regular time and overtime hours. The issue I am having is that if the day of work is split between two projects then it calculates the hours for that date wrong.

For example, on July 10 the employee worked a total of 11 hours. Of those hours, 5 were spend on `WA302` and 6 were spent on `HU047`. When I generate the report for the payroll hours it gives me totals for the two amounts seperately which means the overtime hours will not be calculated properly.

How do I get it to total the hours based on the date for each day worked?

This is the SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    EmployeeLookUptbl.EmployeeDriver,
    EquipmentTimesheettbl.Employee,
    EquipmentTimesheettbl.Date,
    EquipmentTimesheettbl.ProductionHours,
    EquipmentTimesheettbl.NonProductionHours,
    EquipmentTimesheettbl.RepairHours,
    EquipmentTimesheettbl.[Stat Holiday],
    EquipmentTimesheettbl.TravelTime,
    EquipmentTimesheettbl.TruckWash,
    EquipmentTimesheettbl.FirstAid,
    EquipmentTimesheettbl.DesignatedDriver,
    EquipmentTimesheettbl.LOA,
    EquipmentTimesheettbl.[Vehicle Allownance],
    EquipmentTimesheettbl.DaysWorked,
    [ProductionHours]+[NonProductionHours]+[RepairHours] AS TotalHours,
    IIf([TotalHours]>8,8,[TotalHours]) AS RegularHours,
    IIf([totalhours]<8,0,[totalhours]-8) AS Overtime,
    EquipmentTimesheettbl.RPP,
    EmployeeLookUptbl.FirstName,
    EquipmentTimesheettbl.Phase
FROM
    EquipmentTimesheettbl
    LEFT JOIN EmployeeLookUptbl
    ON EquipmentTimesheettbl.Employee = EmployeeLookUptbl.ReportName
WHERE
    (((EquipmentTimesheettbl.Date)
    Between [Enter Start Date] And [Enter End Date]))
ORDER BY EquipmentTimesheettbl.Date;
```

Comment: Hi there, I added my SQL from the query...hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance in trying to figure this one out.  Its been driving me a little nuts...

Answer (score 1):

hours should be a property of the job so you can access it like so:

```
Total.hours = Job.hours + Job2.hours;
```

translates to

```
Total.hours = WA302.hours + HU047.hours;
```

translates to

```
Total.hours = 6+5;
```

Hope that helps your thought process, but unless you show us how you are doing it currently (SQL, Java, etc) we can't help you other then thought process.

Edit: from SQL,

```
sum(hours)
```

and each job should be its own row.

Comment: I have revised my original post to include the Sql stmnt.

Comment: Each job has its own row, which includes date, block its hours of production etc.for that date.  So one date on the form can be shown in the two rows ie one for each block...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `SUM()` to provide a single total of hours.  Also, simplify the query -- remove all the fields you don't need.

Start with this:

```
SELECT Equip.Employee,
    Sum([ProductionHours]) AS TotalProductionHours, 
    Sum([NonProductionHours]) AS TotalNonProductionHours, 
    Sum([RepairHours]) AS TotalRepairHours, 
FROM EquipmentTimesheettbl As Equip
    LEFT JOIN EmployeeLookUptbl As Employee 
    ON Equip.Employee = Employee.ReportName
WHERE
    (((Equip.Date)
    Between [Enter Start Date] And [Enter End Date]))
ORDER BY Equip.Date;
```

Then use it as the basis for a new query.  You can make this one above even more sparse -- save your JOINS for later, if the information they provide are just for the report.

Wherever you see separate lines instead of a total, either remove the field that is forcing the breakout OR insert a GROUP BY clause.  'Date' is a good example of a field that belongs in the `WHERE` clause but NOT in the 'SELECT' clause.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.opengatesw.net/ms-access-tutorials/Access-Articles/Microsoft-Access-Query2.htm) that may help.  Also, Access Help should answer this for you (although just now I didn't find quite what I wanted about this topic).

Also, it is **very important** you not name a table field "Date" as that is an Access reserved keyword!

Comment: The Total Hours field is a sum of all of the hours worked in the project.  When we enter them into the form there are seperate lines for each project on that date. are you saying I need to sum each date seperately on the report and then calculate the regular and overtime hours based on that?  Hours worked on each date determines our overtime not over the week as some payroll is run.  Being that we are logging it changes how the calculations are made.

Comment: All fields are required for this particular report as the payroll system includes this as pay for the period.

Comment: So would it be better if I put in as WorkDate instead for the field name?

Comment: It now totals the hours by work date, so I am going to try to add this to my report, wish me luck....

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are grouping by date and project instead of just the date. Without knowing the schema of your Access database or the query that you are trying to use, it's impossible to know for certain.

From the sound of your question, you want a report which is going to give you subtotals by date and employee.

I know it's not exactly the answer to your problem, but there are tons of tools out there to track employee work and do payroll. Unless you have extremely specific needs, I'd recommend using something like Quickbooks instead of building something in Access. Check out http://quickbooksonline.intuit.com/time-tracking-software. Note I don't even use them, or work for them, but it is almost definitely worth the $40 a month they charge for all of the features.

Comment: On my report only the date is included in the query not the project.  I have not included the project in my query either. We would like to use the access program for this as all of the m3 of production is readily available in it so we can calculate our m3/hr much quicker.

Comment: Oops that should read date is included and grouping is only on it in the report.  No project included either on the report or the query.

Comment: Looking at your query I notice that you are not grouping by date. You should create a query in Access which totals the hours for each user by date first. i.e. the query definition could look like:
SELECT Employee.ID, Timesheet.Date, SUM( Timesheet.[ProductionHours]+Timesheet.[NonProductionHours]+Timesheet.[RepairHours])
FROM EmployeeLookUptbl As Employee
JOIN EquipmentTimesheettbl As Timesheet on Employee.ID = Timesheet.EmployeeID
GROUP BY Employee.ID, Timesheet.Date

Then you can use that query to generate your report by joining it to other tables.